Migrate field values while creating different language version in sitecore
Migrate field values while creating different language versions in Sitecore - I Need to copy all filed values from the English language while creating new language version.
Is there way to achieve this in Content Editor?

Maybe add some more information about what you are trying to do, what is your Sitecore Version, what have you tried?

You can use the below PowerShell snippet to create a reusable Powershell Module:
$sourceLanguageSelector = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/system/Languages"
$destinationLanguageSelector = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/system/Languages"
$dialogParams = @{
    Title = "Dialog title"
    Description = "Description under title"
    OkButtonName = "Execute"
    CancelButtonName = "Close"
    ShowHints = $true
    Parameters = @(
        @{
            Name = "sourceLanguageSelector"
            Title = "Source Language Selector"
            Root = "/sitecore/system/Languages/"
            Tooltip = "Select the Source Language"
        }
         @{
            Name = "destinationLanguageSelector"
            Title = "Destination Language Selector"
            Root = "/sitecore/system/Languages/"
            Tooltip = "Select the Destination Language"
        }
    )
}
$dialogResult = Read-Variable @dialogParams
 
#write-host  $sourceLanguageSelector.Name $destinationLanguageSelector.Name
 
Get-ChildItem -Path "master:" -ID $SitecoreContextItem.ID -Recurse -WithParent |
  ForEach-Object { Add-ItemLanguage $_ -Language $sourceLanguageSelector.Name -TargetLanguage $destinationLanguageSelector.Name -IfExist OverwriteLatest  -IgnoredFields "" }


You can run a powershell extension code to copy content from english to another languages :
Get-ChildItem "master:\content" -Recurse | 
    Add-ItemLanguage -Language "en" -TargetLanguage "fr-fr" -IfExist OverwriteLatest


You can use Smart AddVersionAndCopyContent module in order to achive this. This module helps to add and copy version from any language to other language on the content editor.
This module can be downloaded from below location.
https://github.com/nehemiahj/SmartTools-AddVersionAndCopyContent

You can download the v3 package from the above location and install on your Sitecore solution. Once this module is setup, Add Version And Copy option will come in the content editor for every item as below.

Note: You will need to delete the following command from the App_Config\Include\Sitecore.SharedSource.SmartTools file, as its not a part of this solution.
<command name="ribbon:stfindandreplace" type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SmartTools.Commands.FindAndReplace,Sitecore.SharedSource.SmartTools"/>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Here's a I'm adding basic example of how you can copy field values using PowerShell:
# Specify the item you want to copy fields from and to
$itemPath = "/sitecore/content/Home/MyItem"
$sourceLanguage = "en"  # English
$targetLanguage = "fr"  # French

# Get the item from Sitecore
$item = Get-Item -Path $itemPath

# Copy the fields from the source language to the target language
foreach ($field in $item.Fields) {
    if ($field.HasValue($sourceLanguage)) {
        $value = $field.GetValue($sourceLanguage)
        $field.SetValue($value, $targetLanguage)
    }
}

# Save the item after updating the field values
$item.Editing.EndEdit()


This script copies all field values from the English version to the French version for the specified item.
Hope this help!!

There are multiple ways to migrate field value.
By default, when creating a new language version Sitecore resets to the page template’s Standard Value’s content state. This means you will have to refill the data again for lots of cases in which many fields need to have the English content.
By creating the VersionAdded event handler, you can achieve this.
Follow the steps given in this article by creating a new class and config settings.
The following code will be executed on the VersionAdded event:
<event name="item:versionAdded">
    <handler type="namespace.VersionAddedEvent, assemblyName" method="Process" />
 </event>

public class VersionAddedEvent
 {
   public void Process(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      try
      {
      Item newItem = Event.ExtractParameter(e, 0) as Item;

      if (newItem == null)
      return;

      //Only proceed if master DB
      var masterDB = newItem.Database;
      if (masterDB == null || masterDB.Name.ToLower() != "master")
      return;

      //This check makes sure not to copy content from the english version when creating a      new version of an existing language version e.g. version 2 of DE version
      if (newItem.Versions.Count > 1)
      return;

      //Get the english version of the item, since versions are based on the english version
      Sitecore.Globalization.Language enLanguage = Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en     Sitecore.Data.Items.Item englishVersion = masterDB.GetItem(newItem.ID, enLanguage);

      if (englishVersion == null)
      return;

      ////Copy values from enlish version to the new language version
      //load a fields
      englishVersion.Fields.ReadAll();
      newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
      foreach (Field field in englishVersion.Fields)
      {
         //Make sure to get content from used fields and non-sitecore fields (usually start with      double underscore)
         if (field != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(englishVersion[field.Key]) &&      field.Key.StartsWith("__ false)
         {
            newItem[field.Key] = englishVersion[field.Key];
         }
      }
      newItem.Editing.EndEdit();

      //Get the page's localcomponent folder (if exists)
      var localcomponentsRef = englishVersion.Children.SingleOrDefault(w =>      w.IsDerived(Constants.LocalComponents.ID) && w.Name.ToLower() ==      "localcomponents");

      if (localcomponentsRef == null)
      return;

      //Create a new version of the localcomponents folder in the new language
      var localcomponents = masterDB.GetItem(localcomponentsRef.ID, newItem.Language);
      if (localcomponents.Versions.Count == 0)
      {
         localcomponents.Editing.BeginEdit();
         localcomponents.Versions.AddVersion();
         localcomponents.Editing.EndEdit();
      }

      ////Start creating versions of all datasource items underneath the 'localcomponents'      and moving content to the new lang version
      foreach (var itemRef in localcomponentsRef.Axes.GetDescendants())
       {
         var item = masterDB.GetItem(itemRef.ID, newItem.Language);
         if (item.Versions.Count > 0)
            continue;

         var newVersion = item.Versions.AddVersion();

         itemRef.Fields.ReadAll();
         item.Editing.BeginEdit();
         foreach (Field field in itemRef.Fields)
         {
            if (field != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemRef[field.Key]) &&      field.Key.StartsWith("__ false)
            {
               item[field.Key] = itemRef[field.Key];
            }
         }

         item.Editing.EndEdit();
       }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(ex.ToString(), this);
      }
    }
 }

Reference: https://tamermblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/10/copying-english-version-content-to-new-language-versions/
Another way is to use PowerShell.
    #Get all language versions defined in System/Languages

    $languages = Get-ChildItem /sitecore/System/Languages -recurse | Select $_.name | Where-Object {$_.name -ne "en"} | Select Name

    #Ensuring correct items are updated by comparing the template ID 

    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/media library/MyProjects" -Recurse | Where-Object {'<media item template id>' -contains $_.TemplateID}

    #Bulk update context to improve performance

    New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {

        foreach($item in $items){   

                   foreach($language in $languages){

                        $languageVersion = Get-Item -Path $item.Paths.Path -Language $language.Name

                        #Check if language version already exists

                        if($languageVersion -eq $null){

                            Write-Host "Creating "$language.Name" version for "$item.Name

                            Add-ItemLanguage -Item $item -Language "en" -TargetLanguage $language.Name -IfExist OverwriteLatest                     

                }

            } 

        }

    }

Reference: https://ghanendras.blogspot.com/2020/08/sitecore-powershell-script-to-create.html
Hope it helps!

This is a link only answer, the full answer should be viewable without leaving the SSE site.
